# VueJS3 with Axios and TypeScript - Cannot find variables

Tags: typescript, vue.js, async-await, axios, vuejs3

I can't access the `this.somethingHere` variables inside methods using axios + vuejs3 + ts.

Template code ( not necessary ):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <label for="email"> E-mail </label>
      <input
        type="email"
        placeholder=""
        name="email"
        id="email"
        v-model="email"
      />
      <br /><br />
      <label for="password"> Senha </label>
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder=""
        v-model="password"
        name="password"
        id="password"
      />
      <br /><br />
      <button @click="doLogin" type="button">Enviar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

**IMPORTANT** My vueJS code:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { axios } from "../services/config";

interface Login {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export default {
  data(): { email: string; password: string; data: string } {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      data: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async doLogin(): Promise<void> {
      let userData: Login = {
        email: "thiago.valente@valente.com",
        password: "myPassword",
      };
      try {
        const response: string = await axios.post("/login", userData);
        this.data = response;
      } catch (error) {
        this.data = "Error: " + error;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

When I try to build ( save ) I receive the current error:

```js
ERROR in src/views/Login.vue:52:14
TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type '{ doLogin(): Promise<void>; }'.
    50 |         this.data = response;
    51 |       } catch (error) {
  > 52 |         this.data = "Error: " + error;
       |              ^^^^
    53 |       }
    54 |     },
    55 |   },
```

If I deactivate the typescript that's works fine. Sometimes it's work but if I try to save again I got an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`defineComponent`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components) on the component definition object to get type inference:

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  methods: {
    doLogin() {
      console.log(this.data)
    }
  }
})
```